# Why Is OpenVPN Losing Connection Through CentOS 7 With OVH?

Tags: centos, ip, openvpn, ovh

A few seconds after connecting to my VPN through CentOS 7 on my virtual machine, I lose connection with no errors in the log. This only appears to be happening with CentOS 7/8. OVH documentation (https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-bridging/) covers adding either

```
51.195.234.254 - 255.255.255.255 eth0
51.195.234.0 - 255.255.255.0 eth0
default 51.195.234.254
```

or

```
51.195.234.254 dev eth0
default via 51.195.234.254
```

to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 however this does not help.

Debian 10 (working):

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:ff:3b:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 145.239.xxx.xxx/32 brd 145.239.xxx.xxx scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ff:feff:3bea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r

```
default via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0 
51.195.234.254 dev eth0 scope link
```

After connecting to VPN:
ip r

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
default via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
10.8.0.9 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.10
VPNIP via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0
51.195.234.254 dev eth0 scope link
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
```

CentOS 7:

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:ff:3b:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 145.239.xxx.xxx/32 brd 145.239.xxx.xxx scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 21599969sec preferred_lft 21599969sec
    inet6 fe80::ff:feff:3bea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r

```
default via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0 
51.195.234.254 dev eth0 scope link
```

After connecting to VPN:
ip r

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
default via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0 
10.8.0.9 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.10 
VPNIP via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0 
51.195.234.254 dev eth0 scope link 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
```

I have also tried adding the gateway of the VPN

```
ip route add 5.45.126.254 dev eth0
```

ip r

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.17 dev tun0 
default via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0 
5.45.126.254 dev eth0 scope link 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.17 dev tun0 
10.8.0.17 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.18 
VPNIP via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0 
51.195.234.254 dev eth0 scope link 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.17 dev tun0
```

Could I have to maybe modify `VPNIP via 51.195.234.254 dev eth0` so that it's routed through `VPNIP via 5.45.126.254 dev eth0` ? if so how can I achieve that.

Comment: standard question in this case: does it work with firewall disabled?

Comment: There is no firewall enabled

Comment: The problem is firewall related, looking and showing only IP routing does not help